# Record Audio (radio streaming) from URL React Native

Tags: react-native, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I just made radio streaming player with this library (https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player), but the problem is i need to make feature to record what the radio played. can someone suggest library or modify that library to record audio from url?

Here is my configuration

> Windows 10 CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @2.30GHz
>
> Memory: 2.47 GB / 7.90 GB
>
> Node: 12.2.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
>
> Yarn: 1.15.2 - C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
>
> npm: 6.9.0 - C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\npm.CMD
>
> IDEs: Android Studio: Version 3.4.0.0AI-183.6156.11.34.5692245

```
TrackPlayer.setupPlayer().then(async () => {
            await TrackPlayer.add({
                id: 'trackId',
                url: 'http://mobil.metal-only.de:8000/;',
                title: 'Radio Streaming',
                artist: 'Radio',
                artwork: require('./_resources/smalllogo.png'),
            });
});
```

The code above works perfectly to play radio but the problem is i need to record it when i press record button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `expo-av`

For bare React Native projects, you must ensure that you have installed and [configured the react-native-unimodules package](https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules) before continuing.

and

```
npm install expo-av
```

[Example code for recording](https://github.com/expo/audio-recording-example)

Comment: isnt it record from url? that is record from our audio (sound around) right?

Comment: Yes, you can record the sound you want.